# How do I get oh-my-zsh to automatically download and install plugins at first run?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I really like my .vimrc config file with automatically downloads and installs all dependencies including the plugin manager and all the new while removing plugins which were removed from my .vimrc plugins which allowed me to download my .vimrc from GitHub and get starting without too much headache.
here is an example of the automation:

```
" Install vim-plug if not found
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
      \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
      endif

" Run PlugInstall if there are missing plugins
autocmd VimEnter * if len(filter(values(g:plugs), '!isdirectory(v:val.dir)'))
  \| PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
\| endif


call plug#begin()
```

I'm trying to configure a similar thing for .zshrc and I'm not sure how to start.
I can't figure out how to get ohmyzsh to download plugins.
Can someone please help me?
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Is your `.zshrc` on GitHub? Why not just `git clone https://github.com/YechielWorenklein/home .` or whatever you do for vim?

Comment: my issue is not with vim, I'm trying to get my .zshrc to be like my .vimrc

Comment: I didn't know `.vimrc` could be configured to download plugins.  Maybe you could share a few lines that do that so we can understand what an equivalent would be.

Comment: `autocmd VimEnter * if len(filter(values(g:plugs), '!isdirectory(v:val.dir)')) \| PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC \| endif` @Stewart

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yechiel from the future here...

This was a noob question and I appreciate everyone for not mocking me on it...

**This can be achieved** very easily with a simple shell logic to check if the `oh-my-zsh` directory exists and runs installation command if not.

Example

```bash
[[ -x $HOME/.oh-my-zsh ]] || sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Comment: You asked how to get OMZ to automatically download and install plugins. This doesn't answer that question.

Comment: @MarlonRichert, am obviously assuming a .zshrc with the list of plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple plugin to fully auto-update themes and plugins OhMyZSH

Link to github: [OhMyZsh Full-autoupdate](https://github.com/Pilaton/OhMyZsh-full-autoupdate)